# Proving the relation of differentials

Tags: calculus, differential-forms

Do we need to have concept about differential geometry to rigorously prove $dy=f'\times dx$.Because $dy,dx$ are mere notations in standard calculus and we many a times informally multiply or divide by them in solving differential equations which to me is pretty vague and less rigorous.

Comment: It depends on what you call differential geometry. For functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$, you need to know differential calculus. On manifolds, you need to know differential geometry. Moreover, I think finding a proof will be hard as it is usually set as a definition in differential geometry.

Comment: I mean i am new to calculus and am seeing many imes that people multiply and divide by dx.So I wanted to know the rigor behind this.

Comment: It is just a notation, but it is justified by the fact that if $y = f(x)$ is a function, then the differential form $dy$ is equal to the differential form $f'(x)dx$.

Comment: Isn't this differential form derived from differential geometry or at least some stuffs from university level math?

Comment: In high school, $f' = df/dx$ is to understand as a notation, highlighting the fact that this is a ratio of two infinitesimal quantities. In undergraduate lessons, the concept of differential form is introduced to give rigorous sense to this notation. Differential geometry then gives a generalization of differential calculus on geometric spaces.

Comment: If you search a little bit, you will find dozens of posts here on this very topic. I myself have explained at least a few times that the technique of separation of variables in calculus can be justified carefully with the chain rule.